# Erro ao publicar na AppStore

Tags: ios, xcode, mac, appstore

Coloquei todos os dados no `iTunes Connect` mas há um erro na parte de capturas de tela. Já coloquei uma imagem para `3,5"`, `4"`, `4,7"`, `5,5"` e `iPad` com os tamanhos informados no site. No entanto sempre aparece o erro:

> Carregue ao menos uma captura de tela

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há três soluções possíveis:

1. **[Incompatibilidade de navegador](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21214077/2305521)**: tente com outro navegador, por exemplo `Firefox`
2. **[Problemas com o arquivo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16065781/2305521)**: abra os screenshots com o `Preview` e salve como um novo arquivo.
3. **[Problemas de formato](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11148230/2305521)**: certifique-se de imagens com ao menos `72 dpi`, `RGB`em `.jpeg`, `.jpg`, `.tif`, .`tiff`, ou `.png`.

> Images must be at least 72 dpi, in the RGB color space, and the file must be .jpeg, .jpg, .tif, .tiff, or .png.

**Importante**: se sua aplicação estiver localizada esqueça de verificar os passos **2** e **3** para as todas as versões localizadas.

Comment: ja tentei com outro navegador e salvando as imagens,e as imagens segue no formato correto, mas o erro persiste.

Comment: você subiu as imagens para todas as línguas?

Comment: ah, não! é isso?

Comment: sim, foi isso que eu quis dizer com aplicação localizada, muda para a outra língua e sobe os screenshots dela

Comment: No canto superior direito tem um nome de uma língua seguido de uma setinha para baixo, você clica lá para adicionar a descrição e capturas de tela nos outros idiomas para quais a aplicação está localizada :)

Comment: deu certo valeu, mas na hora de validar pelo xcode aparece "itunes store operation failed,"no software with cfbundlerIdentifier of  be.com.app.key verifi you bundle identifier is correct.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20077/discussion-between-war-lock-and-francesco-perrotti-garcia).

Comment: Valeu funcionou!

Comment: comentei, o site http://appreviewtimes.com/ é bem útil para saber o tempo médio atual de espera! :)

Comment: vai no chat pf...